# HBase Cell Tags returned in Scan but not in Get

Tags: hbase

I am reading HBase Cell tags via HBase client.

I write the tags via Put.addImmutable(cf, col, version, value, tags).

I can verify these tags have been written correctly by scanning HBase:

```
Scan s = new Scan();
    s.setFilter(new PageFilter(100));
    ResultScanner scanner = table.getScanner(s);
    Result[] results = scanner.next(100);
    Arrays.stream(results).forEach(r ->  {
        CellScanner cs = r.cellScanner();
        try {
            while(cs.advance()) {
                byte tagValue = ((KeyValue)cs.current()).getTags()
                        .stream()
                        .filter(tag -> tag.getType() == MY_SPECIAL_TAG_TYPE)
                        .findFirst().orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("No tag found"))
                        .getValue();
                System.out.println("tagValue=" + Bytes.toString(tagValue));
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
        }
    });
```

I always get the correct value that I have set on the put.

However, when I do a get for a row key I know exists - see code below - and try to access the tags, I get no values returned.

```
Get g = new Get(Bytes.toBytes("myKey");

    Result r = table.get(g);

    CellScanner cs = r.cellScanner();
        try {
            while(cs.advance()) {
                byte tagValue = ((KeyValue)cs.current()).getTags()
                        .stream()
                        //.filter(tag -> tag.getType() == MY_SPECIAL_TAG_TYPE)
                        .findFirst().orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("No tag found"))
                        .getValue();
                System.out.println("tagValue=" + Bytes.toString(tagValue));
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
        }
    }
```

Have I made a mistake or is this a limitation of the HBase client API that tags shall not be returned from get queries?

Comment: This only occurs when using the HBaseTestingUtility. This does not occur with an actual instance of HBase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This occurs because HBase Cell tags are not for client side use. They will be returned to the client when the requesting user is a super user. It is not recommended to rely on reading cell tags client side.

Comment: How do I request as a super user ?